# questions related to source code of PHP uniqid()

Tags: php, c, unique-id, gettimeofday, timeval

In PHP source code function uniqid() have following C code:
(I removed some types to shorten it)

```
//...
struct timeval tv;
gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
int sec  = (int) tv.tv_sec;
int usec = (int) (tv.tv_usec % 0x100000);

// The max value usec can have is 0xF423F,
// so we use only five hex digits for usecs.
printf("%08x%05x", sec, usec);
//...
```

If we put criticism aside, they try to produce 64 bit timestamp.

**0xF423F** is probably **CLOCKS_PER_SEC - 1** (CLOCKS_PER_SEC is decimal 1000000),

but where this **0x100000** come from and what could be the reason to use modulus instead of bitwise and?

Comment: Your question can only really be answered by the person that wrote the code, anybody else can only really speculate as to the reason

Comment: I do not agree with you. Code is not that difficult to explain, but I lack good understanding about milliseconds nature calculation.

Comment: `what could be the reason` can't really be answered with anything other than speculation, other than the writer themself

Comment: Good lord this code is awful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

She or he could write the Unique ID as `printf("%08x%08x", sec, usec)`

```
sample output:
55189926000eb16f
5518997900051219
5518997a0005171b
```

The zeros in position 8 to 10 are consistent, they don't add entropy, so he wants to get rid of those zeros. The new UID will be 3 bytes shorter with the same entropy. He could simply use `printf("%08x%05x", sec, usec);`

```
sample output:
55189926eb16f
5518997951219
5518997a5171b
```

But that's on the assumption that usec is guaranteed to be less than 0x100000 otherwise UID will be up to 16 bytes long. You need `% 0x100000` for insurance. It's also the same as `& 0xFFFFF`. Technically the insurance should be `% 1000000 (decimal)`, but it doesn't really matter, it's still the same entropy.

Or we could just use the 16 byte version because saving 3 lousy bytes don't matter these days.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit He's :) statistically correct.

Comment: It's not really impressive code, it makes no difference who takes credit for it.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: Way to miss the point. And to abuse commaen.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Are you just assuming that I am a guy? My first name doesn't reveal anything.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: I don't care what gender you are. Your gender is irrelevant. But you assumed the code author is male, for no reason at all.